# Typecasting char * to struct * in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

`char *constant` is the pointer to the head of my linked list. I'm supposed to be using the global char pointer "constant" in my functions and what I'm doing is -

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int attribute;
    struct Node next;
} Node;


void init(int data)
{
    Node *constant = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    constant->attribute = data;
    
    Node *next = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    next->attribute = data*2;

    constant->next = next;
    next->next = NULL;
    printList();
}


void printList()
{
    Node *temp = (Node *)constant;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->attribute);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

When I call printList in the init function it doesn't print anything, but when I copy the printList code to init it does what it's supposed to. I use "constant" similarly in other functions and it gives me a segmentation fault. How do I fix this?

Comment: `struct Node next;` typo here, must be a pointer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already have a char *constant in your application, you surely don't wanna declare a Node* with the same name.

Remove the Node* from first line of init() to give `constant = malloc(sizeof(Node));` so that you actually use the global variable, and not a local one. You'll also need to cast it anywhere you use it with `((Node*)constant)->next = next;` for instance

Answer (score 0):

In your `init()` function you are a bit confused how you will add the beginning node in your list. You have your global pointer `constant *head;` When you add a node, you declare and allocate for a new temporary node and initialize the member setting `attribute = data;` and `next = NULL;` Once you have your first node allocated, you assign the node address to `head`.

There is no need for an `init()` function, what you really need is an `add()` or `push()` function that simply passes the data as a parameter and then allocates for the node, initializing as above and then assigning to the `next` pointer of the last node in the list. (you can also do what is called *forward-chaining*, where you add a new first node each time, but the nodes in your list end up in reverse order from how they were input.

You can make use of two global pointers, `head` and `tail` where `tail` will always point to the last node in the list. That way you never have to iterate to insert at the end of the list, you just add the new node at `tail->next = node;` and then update tail so it point to the new end node, e.g. `tail = node;`

Presuming your `struct constant` is similar to:

```
typedef struct constant {
    int attribute;
    struct constant *next;
} constant;
```

You can write your `add()` function to handle adding all nodes to your list in order with:

```
constant *head, *tail;
...
constant *add (int data)
{
    constant *node = malloc (sizeof *node);     /* allocate */
    
    if (!node) {                                /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        return NULL;
    }
    node->attribute = data;                     /* assign data to attribute */
    node->next = NULL;                          /* initialize next NULL */
    
    if (!head)                                  /* if 1st node */
        head = tail = node;                     /* assign node to both head, tail */
    else {  /* otherwise */
        tail->next = node;                      /* set tail->next = node */
        tail = node;                            /* update tail to point to last node */
    }
    
    return node;                /* return pointer to added node to indicate success */
}
```

Both your `print()` and `free_list()` functions can simply loop over each node either outputting the node attribute, or freeing the node. The only caveat in `free_list()` is you must increment to the next node before deleting the current. Both functions are shown below:

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct constant {
    int attribute;
    struct constant *next;
} constant;

constant *head, *tail;

constant *add (int data)
{
    constant *node = malloc (sizeof *node);     /* allocate */
    
    if (!node) {                                /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        return NULL;
    }
    node->attribute = data;                     /* assign data to attribute */
    node->next = NULL;                          /* initialize next NULL */
    
    if (!head)                                  /* if 1st node */
        head = tail = node;                     /* assign node to both head, tail */
    else {  /* otherwise */
        tail->next = node;                      /* set tail->next = node */
        tail = node;                            /* update tail to point to last node */
    }
    
    return node;                /* return pointer to added node to indicate success */
}

void prn_list (void)
{
    /* loop over each node using iter and output attribute for each node */
    for (constant *iter = head; iter; iter = iter->next)
        printf (" %d", iter->attribute);
    
    putchar ('\n');
}

void free_list (void)
{
    /* loop over each node, but increment to next in list before deleting current */
    for (constant *iter = head; iter;) {
        constant *victim = iter;
        iter = iter->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        add (i + 1);
    
    prn_list();
    free_list();
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_global_head
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I'm supposed to use an init function, it's a part of the question. "constant" is the name of my char pointer, and I've edited the post to include the structure definition.
Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: I guessed pretty close. Sorry for the late replay, power went out right after I posted.